# If $P$ minimal over $\operatorname{ann} M$, and every element not in $P$ is a nonzero divisor on $M$, then a power of $P$ annihilates $M$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, proof-writing, proof-explanation, modules

Let $P$ be a prime ideal of the Noetherian ring $R$, and let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module.

**Proposition:** If $P$ minimal over $\operatorname{ann} M$, and every element not in $P$ is a nonzero divisor on $M$, then a power of $P$ annihilates $M$.

> > > [image]

---

I don't understand why proving the special case also shows the general statement we want to prove.

**Why is it sufficient to localize?**

Answer (score 2):

Showing that a power of $P$ annihilates $M$ is just showing that $P^n\subseteq\operatorname{ann}_R(M)$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So, suppose that the result holds for local rings, and let $R_P$ be the localization of $R$ at $S:=R\setminus P$ and $M_P$ the localization of $M$ at $S$.

We claim the localization map $M\rightarrow M_P$ is injective. Indeed, recall that $m$ lies in the kernel of this map if and only if there is an element $s\in S$ such that $s\cdot m=0$. Since every element of $S$ is a non-zero divisor on $M$ by hypothesis, this will happen if and only if $m=0$.

Now, by the result for local rings, there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $P_P^n\subseteq\operatorname{ann}_{R_P}(M_P)$. We claim that this implies $P^n\subseteq\operatorname{ann}_R(M)$. Indeed, let $p\in P^n$ and $m\in M$. We have $p\big/1\in P_P^n$, so in particular $p\big/1\cdot m\big/1=0\big/1$; ie, $p\cdot m\big/1=0\big/1$. But now injectivity of the map $M\rightarrow M_P$ implies $p\cdot m=0$, as desired.